# PHP Laravel save() is saving even when the condition is false

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

> A null value is value is saved every time the textbox is empty. I need the code to not save anything in the database if the textbox is left empty.

```
    if('questionName'!=''){
        $questionName = NEW Question();
        $questionName->question_name = request('questionName');
        $questionName->user_id = Auth::user()->user_id;
        $questionName->save();
        $questionid = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
    }
    elseif('questionName'==''){
        $questionid = request('question_id');
    }
```

Comment: because 'questionName' is always not equals to ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a string i.e `'questionName'` with `''` that is always true.

> **Change this**

```
if('questionName'!='')
```

> **to**

```
if ($request->input('questionName') != '' )
```